# flutter: widget.controller != null : is not true

Tags: flutter

when I use widget `Scrollbar` to add a scroll bar to my `ListView`, this assertion was thrown although the layout behaves normally. Complete info and related code are below:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SCHEDULER LIBRARY ╞═
I/flutter ( 4453): The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
I/flutter ( 4453): 'package:flutter/src/material/scrollbar.dart': Failed assertion: line 111 pos 20: 'widget.controller
I/flutter ( 4453): != null': is not true.
I/flutter ( 4453):
I/flutter ( 4453): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
I/flutter ( 4453): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
I/flutter ( 4453): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
I/flutter ( 4453):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
I/flutter ( 4453):
I/flutter ( 4453): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 4453): #2      _ScrollbarState.didChangeDependencies.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/scrollbar.dart:111:20)
I/flutter ( 4453): #3      SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1113:15)
I/flutter ( 4453): #4      SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1060:9)
I/flutter ( 4453): #5      SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:968:5)
I/flutter ( 4453): #9      _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:261:10)
I/flutter ( 4453): #10     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:219:3)
I/flutter ( 4453): (elided 5 frames from class _AssertionError and dart:async)
I/flutter ( 4453): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 4453): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/material/scrollbar.dart': Failed assertion: line 111 pos 20: 'widget.controller !=
 null': is not true.
```

```
Scrollbar(
                          isAlwaysShown: true,
                          child: ListView(
                            controller: sc,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(ScreenUtil.dp(22), 0, ScreenUtil.dp(23), ScreenUtil.dp(8.13)),
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Html(data: """$html""",),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

Comment: is the 'sc' value initialized?

Comment: @KuKu yeah, I init it in function initState(){} as `sc = ScrollController()`

Comment: share code of initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in the stack trace reads:

> 'package:flutter/src/material/scrollbar.dart': Failed assertion: line 111 pos 20: 'widget.controller I/flutter ( 4453): != null'

So basically the `Scrollbar` widget cannot find any `ScrollController` attached to it.

If you go to the official documentation of the `Scrollbar` ([here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scrollbar-class.html)) widget class, it indicates that if the `isAlwaysShownFlag` ([here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scrollbar/isAlwaysShown.html)) is set to `true`, you need to provide a `ScrollController` to the `Scrollbar` widget.

> Indicates whether the Scrollbar should always be visible.
> When false, the scrollbar will be shown during scrolling and will fade out otherwise.
> When true, the scrollbar will always be visible and never fade out.
> The controller property must be set in this case. It should be passed the relevant Scrollable's ScrollController.

Try adding the same `ScrollController` to the `Scrollbar` widget as well, and it should solve your problem.

So your widget should look like this:

```
Scrollbar(
      isAlwaysShown: true,
      controller: sc, // <--- should be same as the one passed to `ListView`
      child: ListView(
        controller: sc,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
            ScreenUtil.dp(22), 0, ScreenUtil.dp(23), ScreenUtil.dp(8.13)),
        children: <Widget>[
          Html(
            data: """$html""",
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. Earlier, I read the doc and tried to add a `controller` to the `Scrollbar` but another assertion was thrown(about the `_position.isNotEmpty`) because I init a new `controller` for the `Scrollbar`. So could you please explain for me why should they share the same `controller`?

Comment: In the error it reads: `_position.isNotEmpty`. Clearly the `Scrollbar` can't find the scroll position, updated by the `ListView`. As per `ScrollController`'s doc: `A scroll controller creates a ScrollPosition to manage the state specific to an individual Scrollable widget.`. So the `Scrollbar` widget uses the position value from the same `ScrollController` & draws the actual scrollBar view on the screen, showing the current scroll position of the actual `Scrollable` widget (`ListView`). If we use a different controller, the value will never be updated & the scrollbar cannot draw anything.